# g rendered ouside of svg in d3.js implemented in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, d3.js

When i try to generate a word cloud using d3,js, the g element is rendered ouside of svg when i give data to it via api call. But when i supply data locally, it is working properly.The angular ts code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as D3 from 'd3';
import { PopulatTopicsService } from '../services/populat-topics.service';
declare let d3: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-populat-topics',
  templateUrl: './populat-topics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./populat-topics.component.css']
})
export class PopulatTopicsComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private popularService : PopulatTopicsService){}
//local data- works fine
    //   data = [
    //     {text: 'Bob',size:33,cuscolor: '#abaaea'},
    //     {text: 'Robin',size:12,cuscolor: '#abaaea'},
    //     {text: 'Anne',size:41,cuscolor: '#abaaea'},
    //     {text: 'Mark',size:16,cuscolor: '#abaaea'},
    //     {text: 'Joe',size:39,cuscolor: '#abaaea'}
    // ];
 network ="FB";
 startDate ="01/04/2018";
 endDate ="07/04/2018";
 brandId ="720";
 userId ="20615";
 period ="LASTWEEK";

data =[];
wdata = "u gh h xfg fg  gf";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.popularService.wordCloud(this.userId,this.startDate,this.endDate,this.brandId,this.period,this.network).subscribe(res => 
      {
        console.log(res);
      this.data = res;
      console.log(this.data['term']);
      let cls = this;
      // this.data = this.wdata.split(' ').map(function(d) {
      //   return {text: d, size: cls.getRandom()};
      // });
      this.setup();
      this.buildSVG();
      this.populate();
      }
    );



  }
  // data = [{'number':1},{'number':2}];

private svg;               // SVG in which we will print our chart
private margin: {          // Space between the svg borders and the actual chart graphic
  top: number,
  right: number,
  bottom: number,
  left: number
};
private width: number;      // Component width
private height: number;     // Component height
private fillScale;          // D3 scale for text color
tempData = [];
private getRandom() {
  let cls = this;
  let size = 10 + Math.random() * 100;
  if(size > 70 && this.tempData.length <= 10) {
    this.tempData.push(size);
  }

  if(this.tempData.length > 10 && size > 14) {
    return 12;
  }

  return size;
}

private setup() {
  this.margin = {
    top   : 10,
    right : 10,
    bottom: 10,
    left  : 10
  };
  this.width = 1200;
  this.height = 450;

  let minFontSize: number = 18 ;
  let maxFontSize: number = 96 ;
  this.fillScale = D3.scaleOrdinal(D3.schemeCategory10);
//  this.fillScale = ['#abaaea','#abaaea','#abaaea','#abaaea','#abaaea'];
}

private buildSVG() {
  this.svg = D3.select("#wordCloud")
                  .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', this.width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
                  .attr('height', this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ~~(this.width / 2) + ',' + ~~(this.height / 2) + ')');
}

private populate() {
  let fontFace: string = 'Roboto';
  let fontWeight: string = 'normal';
  let spiralType: string = 'archimedean';

  d3.layout.cloud()
    .size([this.width, this.height])
    .words(this.data)
    .padding(0)
    .rotate(() => (~~(Math.random() * 2) * 0))
    .font(fontFace)
    .fontWeight(fontWeight)
    .fontSize(d => (d.size))
    .spiral(spiralType)
    .on('end', () => {
      this.drawWordCloud(this.data);
    })
    .start();
}

private drawWordCloud(words) {
  this.svg
      .selectAll('text')
      .data(words)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .style('font-size', d => 20 + 'px')
      .style('fill', this.fillScale)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')rotate(' + d.rotate + ')')
      .attr('class', 'word-cloud')
      .text(d => {
        return d.term;
      });
}
}
```

MY HTML IS GIVEN BELOW:

```
 <div class ="tag_cloud-wrap" id ="wordCloud" ></div>
```

MY CSS:

```
      .tag_cloud-wrap {
    clear: both;
    margin: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSON DATA obtained throug api call is:

```
0
:
{term: "#NYIAS", score: "-Infinity", normalizedScore: 0, totalTermFreq: 2, totalDocFreq: 2, …}
1
:
{term: "TORQUE", score: 0, normalizedScore: 0, totalTermFreq: 1, totalDocFreq: 1, …}
2
:
{term: "RS", score: 0, normalizedScore: 0, totalTermFreq: 1, totalDocFreq: 1, …}
3
:
{term: "SPORTBACK", score: 0, normalizedScore: 0, totalTermFreq: 1, totalDocFreq: 1, …}
4
:
{term: "COLOR", score: 0, normalizedScore: 0, totalTermFreq: 1, totalDocFreq: 1, …}
```

I am assigning term as text to word cloud.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The local data structure is different than the one you receive from the api.